# Replace DIV Element When Clicked On It 3 Times With Cookie Logging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, element

I am trying to make the replacement of div element once being clicked 3 times work with cookie logging. I want the webserver to remember when the element has been replaced once it was clicked 3 times. Maybe with a cookie? Neverless currently when, I refresh the page the element returns back to unchanged state like it was by default.

I already coded a div element that changes id when being clicked on 3 times. It replaces with a different id but it doesn't cookies don't log it so after, I refresh the page it returns to default state, unreplaced.

```
function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
    let count = 0;
    div1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        count ++;
        if (count === 3) {
            elem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
        }
    });
}

const div1 = document.querySelector('#id-1');

// pre-made second div for future replacement
const div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.id = 'id-2';
div2.innerText = 'div 2';

replaceAfter3Clicks(div1, div2);
```

```
<div id="id-1"> div 1 </div>
```

Comment: Look for [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: What have you tried so far? It sounds like you know exactly what you want, and it doesn't seem like you'll have a problem figuring it out. If you run into an issue, then post the code that caused you an issue, and we can help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do exactly what you want. I'm using localStorage instead of cookies for many reasons and you'll likely want to use it too unless you need to process the data server-side.

Give a look to `window.localStorage` and `window.sessionStorage` on MDN for additional info.

If you look carefully in your web inspector, you'll find the current page data storage, it will help you while debugging.

Please let me know if you have any doubts.

```
function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
    let count = 0;
    div1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        count ++;
        if (count === 3) {
            elem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
            localStorage.setItem('clicked', 'true');
        }
    });
}

const div1 = document.querySelector('#id-1');

// pre-made second div for future replacement
const div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.id = 'id-2';
div2.innerText = 'div 2';

if (localStorage.getItem('clicked') === 'true') {
    div1.parentNode.replaceChild(div1, div2);
} else {
  replaceAfter3Clicks(div1, div2);
}
```

```
<div id="id-1"> div 1 </div>
```

Comment: I would suggest moving the conditional inside of the click function, otherwise this will only work if you reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need to store this information in some way. Whether in the database or in Cookie, sessionStorage, localStorage ... Here's an example of how to do it using sessionStorage

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('div')){
            const div1 = document.querySelector('#id-1');
            var newDiv = sessionStorage.getItem('div');
            var newId = sessionStorage.getItem('id')
            div1.id = newId;
            div1.innerText = newDiv;
        }
    });

    function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
        let count = 0;
        div1.addEventListener('click', () => {
            count ++;
            if (count === 3) {
                sessionStorage.clear(); // Clear all sessionStorage
                sessionStorage.setItem('div', "div 2"); // First param is the name and the second is the value
                sessionStorage.setItem('id', "id-2");// First param is the name and the second is the value
                elem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
            }
         });
    }

    const div1 = document.querySelector('#id-1');

    // pre-made second div for future replacement
    const div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div2.id = 'id-2';
    div2.innerText = 'div 2';
    replaceAfter3Clicks(div1, div2);
```

In the first part we check if there is a value stored in sessionStorage
If it exists we take the values ​​and change in div